# There is a bug in careers.stackoverflow.com and no easy way to report it

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

Tried to add a project. After I clicked save, it took me to this screen.

[image: Imgur]

I tried to go back and do it again and it still happened, plus it deleted what I wrote! Plus there is no way to save! I keep clicking save and it keeps reloading.

It is caused by listing too many Technologies for an 'Apps & Software'.

Where shall I mail the invoice?

Comment: Seems like you're having style sheet issues... Are there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Take note, web devs; this is what happens when you don’t degrade gracefully.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII When I have the console open, it crashes the browser! Seems like Google has a bug too! (Only crashes the tab in Chrome.)

Comment: Did you try with a clean browser (i.e. no extensions)?

Comment: Do you have javascript enabled?  Careers simply will not work without it as of a year ago or so.

Comment: Currently I am unable to reproduce this issue. Any more specific information you could provide would be very helpful.

Comment: @rossipedia It is caused by listing too many Technologies for an 'Apps & Software'.